# Streaming Example From "Sinatra: Up and Running" Not Working

Tags: sinatra

I am trying to run this example from the book *Sinatra: Up and Running* p. 46, but can't get it to work.  Here's the program code:

```rb
require 'sinatra'

before do
  content_type :txt
end

connections = []

get '/consume' do
  stream(:keep_open) do |out|
    # store connection for later on
    connections << out
    # remove connection when closed properly
    out.callback { connections.delete(out) }
    # remove connection when closed due to an error
    out.errback do
      logger.warn 'we just lost a connection!'
      connections.delete(out)
    end
  end
end

get '/broadcast/:message' do
  connections.each do |out| 
    out << "#{Time.now} -> #{params[:message]}" << "\n"
  end
  "Sent #{params[:message]} to all clients."
end
```

The instructions for testing the code are as follows:

```
It’s a little tricky to demonstrate the behavior in text, but a good demonstration would
be to start the application, then open a web browser and navigate to http://localhost:
4567/consume. Next, open a terminal and use cURL to send messages to the server.
    $ curl http://localhost:4567/broadcast/hello
    Sent hello to all clients.
If you look back at the web browser, you should see that the content of the page has
been updated with a time stamp and the message that you sent via the terminal. The
connection remains open, and the client continues to wait for further information from
the server.
```

When I follow these instruction, I get no errors, but the message "hello" does not appear in the browser.  I am running Sinatra on with Webrick.  Why is it not working?

Thanks!

### UPDATE (Konstantin's Thin Suggestion)

I now start thin and perform the two steps described in the book and the OP.  You can see that thin does indeed receive both requests.  However, I am still not seeeing the output "hello" in the browser.

```
>rackup
>> Thin web server (v1.4.1 codename Chromeo)
>> Maximum connections set to 1024
>> Listening on 0.0.0.0:9292, CTRL+C to stop
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2012 12:48:03] "GET /consume HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0900
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2012 12:48:03] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 447 0.0000
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2012 12:49:02] "GET /broadcast/hello HTTP/1.1" 200 26 0.00
00
127.0.0.1 - - [13/Aug/2012 12:57:00] "GET /consume HTTP/1.1" 200 - 0.0000
```

Perhaps the mistake is in my `configu.ru` file:

```
require './streaming.rb'

run Sinatra::Application
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run Sinatra on Thin. `:keep_open` is not supported on Webrick. Make sure you're running Sinatra 1.3.3 or later.

Comment: Gotta love when the author of the book answers your question :)  Really enjoying the book, btw.  Still can't get the example to work, though, even with Thin.  See my update to the OP.

Comment: wasn't sure if you saw my last comment -- any ideas why it's still not working?  Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, this is a known bug in Sinatra when using Thin with `rackup`. If you start the server instead with `ruby streaming.rb`, it will work. I fixed this issue a while back, but haven't managed to release a new version of Sinatra yet. I'm sorry, I'll take care of it ASAP.

Comment: I just released Sinatra 1.3.3, which should fix your issue.

Comment: Thanks! I got it working now.  Only one strange thing: When I hit the consume page, it loads forever.  If I wanted to prevent that would I need to establish the connection via ajax?

Comment: That's not strange, that's cause you do infinite streaming. If you mean you don't see anything, then it might be related to your browser buffering. If you want to use this via ajax, I recommend you look into Server Sent Events. Sinatra even comes with an example chat implementation: https://github.com/sinatra/sinatra/blob/master/examples/chat.rb

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem.  To speed up the response, I used

```
before do
  content_type 'text/event-stream'
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The second route has to be a POST:

```
post '/broadcast/:message' do
  connections.each do |out|
    out << "#{Time.now} -> #{params[:message]}" << "\n"
  end

  "Sent #{params[:message]} to all clients."
end
```

After that, you will also have to POST your message to the server:

```
curl -vX POST 127.0.0.1:4567/broadcast/hello
```